# Live video streaming over UDP?

Tags: linux, video-streaming, udp, x264

What options are currently available for live streaming of video over UDP?

Current solution uses libx264 and wowza media server, to serve up an rtmp stream.  Unfortunately it's communicating over TCP, and while this is working okay locally I now have to serve up video streams offshore to India.  There is some latency and packet loss, and I think the way TCP guarantees delivery is exacerbating problems.  It is for an interactive application so low latency is critical, video quality less so.

The only solution I'm currently aware of for video streaming over UDP is Flash Media Server v4 using rtmfp.  However this is not an option at the moment because they only support Windows Server or Redhat/CentOS (want something debian based).

Answer (score 1):

I think the most popular method of streaming video via UDP is [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol)/[RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol). Gstreamer should support this and there are probably also some dedicated RTSP/RTP servers available for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your setup or needs, but check out VideoLAN/VLC. Its a versatile tool for many viewing/streaming needs. Check it out at:
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html
http://www.videolan.org/